# Dojo dateTextBox onChange to reflect same date in another textbox on change

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following Dojo dateTextBox date picker:

```
<input type="text" id="startDate" data.dojo.id="startDate" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" value=new Date(year month,day); constraints={datePattern:\'yyyy-MM-dd\'} onchange="document.getElementById(\'endDate\').value = this.value;"/>
```

Which I want whenever I select a date, onchange the same date is reflected in another textbox:

```
<script>
    /* DOJO framework - setup code */    
    dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
</script>
<input type="text" id="endtDate" data.dojo.id="Enddate" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" constraints={datePattern:\'yyyy-MM-dd\'} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have following two **dijit.form.DateTextBox** :-

```
<input id="box1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox"/>

<input id="box2" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox"/>
```

Then to copy the date from box1 to box2 use this :-

```
dijit.byId("box2").set('value', dijit.byId("box1").get('value'));
```

Comment: so @Neelesh do I add the `dijit.byId("box2").set('value', dijit.byId("box1").get('value'));` to `onchange something like: <input id="box1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" onchange="dijit.byId("box2").set('value', dijit.byId("box1").get('value'));" />` ?

Comment: Yes add this on ``onChange``. Refer http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ua2gg/  to know how to attach ``onchange`` event on DateTextBox

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippets.
As @Neelesh saif, in the onchage of startdate you need to update the value of the enddate widget (and not the value of the enddate input)...
This is the main difference with your code.

```js
require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(DateTextBox){
    var endDateTextBox = new DateTextBox({
      constraints:{datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd'}
    }, "endDate");
  
    var startDateTextBox = new DateTextBox({
      constraints:{datePattern:'yyyy-MM-dd'},
      onChange: function() {
        endDateTextBox.set('value', startDateTextBox.get('value'));
      }
    }, "startDate");
    
  
    startDateTextBox.startup();
    endDateTextBox.startup();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<div class="tundra">
  start date: <input id="startDate" type="text" />
  end date: <input id="endDate" type="text" />
</div>
```